# Deploy both .html embedded form and .bpmn model using rest API

Tags: camunda

according this [article](https://medium.com/@stephenrussett/deploying-embedded-forms-with-camunda-rest-api-84cf8010f8c1)  its possible to deploy both bpmn model and its embedded form with camunda API requests. the problem is that I dont want to use curl tools. I need to deploy both .bpmn model and .html form files with [statndard camunda API post method](https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.14/reference/rest/deployment/post-deployment/) .
I’ve ever do this to deploy my .bpmn model with generated forms type. but righ now I want to deploy embedded forms (as a seperate .html file). now, how can i upload both of these files with rest API?
( I know that i should use ‘embedded:deployment:sampleEmbeddedForm.html’ in modeler form key)
In addition, I use postman to test these rest APIs.
I would be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: So not curl. Which tool do you want to use to deploy?

Comment: @rob2universe: postman

Comment: @MohammadAzizi This blog should be useful in understanding this snenario..

https://medium.com/@stephenrussett/deploying-embedded-forms-with-camunda-rest-api-84cf8010f8c1

Answer (score 1):

according to help of a friend that the answer is posted [here](https://forum.camunda.org/t/deploy-both-html-embedded-form-and-bpmn-model-using-rest-api/25290), its possible by adding a new body parameter, as name as form name.

[image]